# IBM MQ: Establishing an SSL connection

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

We're struggling to get IBM MQ to work across SSL.

We've been provided with the certificate chain for the remote host and installed into the Windows Certificate Store (Local Machine). These all look valid.

We're using the following connection properties:

```
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, "other-server.com");            
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"); 
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, "*SYSTEM"); 
        connectionProperties.Add("CertificateLabel", "ibmwebspheremqmywindowsusernamewithoutdomain"); 
        MQEnvironment.SSLCertRevocationCheck = true;
```

We've established that the "CertificateLabel" is the "Friendly name" in Windows parlance.

We've proven unencrypted communication and network-level configuration.

We're using 8.0.0.7 client.

These are the issues we've come across:

- All secure communications fail  with a 2538 error. (MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045380_.htm)
- No success setting the Friendly Name to `ibmwebspheremq` and `ibmwebspheremqmywindowsusername@domain` and `ibmwebspheremqmywindowsusernamewithoutdomain`

General questions:

- Are we correct in assuming that we can install generated certificates exclusively in the Windows Certificate Store?
- Is the 2538 error even related to SSL communications? It *feels* like a network error, though there is that final point in the referenced error documentation.
- Is there anywhere we can look for more informative error information? eg. relating to the SSL trust chain to see if there is an issue there?

Comment: What error is produced on the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG when you get the 2538?

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no error. Or, should I say, no error was forthcoming from the owner of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the following line:

```
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.SSL_PEER_NAME_PROPERTY, "otherserver.com");
```

Turns out that:

1. It needs it in a canonical format, so `DN=`, etc.
2. You don't even need that line

---

Though we did learn a few things along the way:

- The line:

  `connectionProperties.Add("CertificateLabel", "ibmwebspheremqmyusername");`

  Is the string `ibmwebspheremq` plus your *Windows* username (without your domain) *and* the label should be set on the *Friendly name* of your client machine's outgoing certificate NOT including the username.
- The various folders inside your Windows certificate store are significant. The intermediate CAs should be correctly filed.

Comment: Point to note about the `PeerName`. You need it to make sure that you don't trust _any_ server with the CA you're using.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly how the "various folders inside your Windows certificate store are significant". I'm trying to do exactly what you've done, but so far I just run into a MQRC_KEY_REPOSITORY_ERROR.

Comment: @Ykok The "folders" inside the Certificates MMC snap-in are significant in terms of their purpose. So Intermediate CA certs need to be in the Intermediate store, server certs in the Personal (known as "My" internally) store, etc.

Comment: Just to add to this that ta least when using .net client v. 9.2.0.1 on Windows platform there seems to be a very strange handling of the certificate label. The code in the driver will compare `FriendlyName.ToLower()=CertificateLabel`,  meaning that if your certificate friendly name has uppercase letters, you need to specify _CertificateLabel_ all in lowercase.